# AWS EC2 ECS No Container Instances were found in your cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy a dockerized python app using ECS, I followed this tutorial but ran into problems:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs3tyVgiBQQ

The cluster is created and an ECS instance appears in the EC2 menu:
https://ibb.co/GR1SMDD

But no ECS instances appear in the ECS menu:
https://ibb.co/QjwypHt

I created a task and defined a container, similar to what's shown at that point in the video:
https://youtu.be/zs3tyVgiBQQ?t=619

When I'm about to run a new task, in the cluster menu, most fields are already filled with what I wrote for the task above, but when I 'run task', this happens:
https://ibb.co/BPvG6rh

Unable to run task

No Container Instances were found in your cluster.

I've been looking for solutions for a few days now, but I'm new to AWS, and I'm running out of ideas, so any help on how to solve this, step-by-step, is very appreciated

Comment: What is your user-data for the instances?

Comment: If this is the shell instructions executed at launch, I didn't specify anything.
I followed the tutorial and ran into issues that I tried to solve before going further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't wrote your **user-data** with your ecs cluster name, then your EC2 instances will not register with the cluster. You have to explicitly register them with the cluster using user-data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyClusterName" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

as explained in [Bootstrapping container instances with Amazon EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html) .